# Terminal Server 2012 keeps logging in user with Temp Profile

Tags: terminal

Have a 2012 Terminal Server and a 2008R2 Profile server. When a user logs onto the 2012 terminal server who has a roaming profile it keeps using a temporary profile and will not load the domain profile or saved mapped drives as it is a temporary profile.

Comment: Guess, you forgot to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many potential causes for temporary profiles.

Your best first option is to run SysInternals' Process Explorer, and search for the account's user profile directory that should be used to see what process has open handles to it.  E.g. C:\Users\username, not the temporary profile directory.  AND what files may still be open.